# Jquery UI for button returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to apply JQuery UI for button but I can't achieve it. I am getting error like **Error: TypeError: $(...).button is not a function**. I have added a correct js library but it's not working.

**Code:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Button - Default functionality</title>
    <link href="../../Content/flick/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], button" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" value="A submit button" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you have jQuery included and the CSS for jQuery UI but not the JavaScript for jQuery UI.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Oops I made a silly mistake. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jQuery-ui.js file,

you need to include the jquery-ui.js file after jquery library is included

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `jQuery UI.js`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"/>
```

**button()** - represent a method in jQuery UI.js not in css.

check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbzqA/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```